# Arrays - Averaging

Tags: java, arrays

I am having difficulty with the `subAverage` class.It doesn't seem to function properly when I use the main method. Basically the `subAverage` averages the items in an array within the start and ending indexes inclusive. However, when I run this I get

```
3
6
3
```

when I should get

```
3
9
6
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Weight {

    int[] data;

    Weight(int[] init) {

        data = new int[init.length + 1];

        for (int j = 0; j < init.length; j++) {
            data[j] = init[j];
        }
    }

    int subAverage(int start, int end) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = start; j <= end; j++) {
            sum = data[j] + sum;
        }
        return sum / (end - start + 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] values = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11};
        Weight june = new Weight(values);

        if (values.length % 2 == 0) {
            int firstHalf = june.subAverage(0, values.length / 2 - 1);
            int secondHalf = june.subAverage(values.length / 2, values.length);
            int difference = Math.abs(secondHalf - firstHalf);
            System.out.println(firstHalf);
            System.out.println(secondHalf);
            System.out.println(difference);
        }

        if (values.length % 2 == 1) {
            int firstHalf = june.subAverage(0, values.length / 2);
            int secondHalf = june.subAverage(values.length / 2, values.length);
            int difference = Math.abs(secondHalf - firstHalf);
            System.out.println(firstHalf);
            System.out.println(secondHalf);
            System.out.println(difference);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is with your initialization code of data[]

```
data = new int[init.length + 1];
```

it should be

```
data = new int[init.length];
```

and then the problem is with subAverage loop condition

```
for (int j = start; j <= end; j++) {
```

it should be

```
for (int j = start; j < end; j++) {
```

and another problem with the calling code

```
int secondHalf = june.subAverage(values.length / 2, values.length);
```

it should be

```
int secondHalf = june.subAverage(values.length / 2, values.length - 1);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is lying in this line

`int secondHalf = june.subAverage(values.length / 2, values.length);`

You can fix this like the following.

`int secondHalf = june.subAverage(values.length / 2, values.length - 1);`

Answer (score 2):

Issue lies in accessing the index of array..  Try this for secondHalf

```
int secondHalf = june.subAverage(values.length / 2, values.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if (values.length % 2 == 0) {
        int firstHalf = june.subAverage(0, values.length / 2 - 1);
        int secondHalf = june.subAverage(values.length / 2, values.length);
```

to

```
if (values.length % 2 == 0) {
        int firstHalf = june.subAverage(0, values.length / 2 - 1);
        int secondHalf = june.subAverage(values.length / 2, values.length-1);
```

similarly in 2nd if.
Because there is one additional index is added to denominator by one from which you are calculating average **(end+start+1)**.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this line:

```
return sum / (end - start + 1);
```

When you are calling the `subAverage` method for the second half of your list, you are sending in 6 and 3 for the `end` and `start` respectively. Thus, you are dividing the sum by 4, but you only added 3 values. To take the correct average, you need to do:

```
return sum / (end - start);
```

Additionally, there's a problem with iterating from 3 to 6 inclusive over an array of 6 elements. The indexing of this array is from 0 to 5, so performing this iteration should throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. So, I'm not sure how you're getting those results.

Answer (score 1):

Use "int secondHalf =june. subAverage(values.length / 2, values.length - 1);"

Here values.length will be 6...while your loop should end at 5 (0 - 5)...so use values.length-1.